# Will spring cloud data flow (SCDF) server emit notifications?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible for the Spring cloud data flow server to emit notifications whenever applications are deployed and undeployed.

I want to write a java code, that receives above notification from the SCDF Server. After receiving notification, host & port details of those applications will be extracted.

Those host and port details will be configured in a JSON file, so that prometheus will dynamically discover and monitor the targets using file based service discovery mechanism.

Comment: If you deploy dataflow to CloudFoundry or Kuberenetes the Prometheus Proxy does all the heavy lifting and all metrics are collected for deployed task and stream applications.

Comment: Feel free to log a feature request on https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues